# How to set ref to multiple models in Mongoose Schema definition?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to create Model something like this:

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    text: { type: String, default: '' },
    replyFor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post', default: null },
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  }
);

const CommentModel = model('Comment', CommentSchema);

module.exports = CommentModel;
```

The comment is comment for some post so in replyFor ref may be ref: 'Post' or it can be comment for other comment so ref: 'Comment'

So I need something like so:

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    text: { type: String, default: '' },
    replyFor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment Post', default: null },
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  }
);
```

So I need some how make some sort of generic reference.

Comment: Can it be so that I don't need to set ref at all: replyFor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, default: null }?

Comment: Is ref need just for populate reasons?

Comment: Or some sort of type system to determine that it for exact Model type?